# Get all BigQuery Query jobs across organisation that reference a specific table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

**Problem Statement**

We're a large organisation (7000+ people) with many BigQuery projects. My team own a highly used set of approx 250 tables. We are aware of some data quality issues, but need to prioritise which tables we focus our efforts on.

In order to prioritise our effort, we plan to calculate two metrics for each table:

1. Monthly total count of query jobs referencing that table
2. Total number of distinct destination tables referencing that table

However, we are stuck on one aspect -- how do you access all the query jobs across the entire org that reference a specific table?

**What we've tried**

We've tried using the following query to find all query jobs referencing a table:

```sql
select count(*) from 
`project-a`.`region-qualifier`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
where job_type = 'QUERY'
and referenced_tables.project_id = 'project-a'
and referenced_tables.dataset_id = 'dataset-b'
and referenced_tables.table_id = 'table-c'
```

Unfortunately, this is only showing query jobs that are kicked off with `project-a` as the billing project (afaik).

**Summary**

Imagine we have 50+ GCP projects that could be executing queries referencing a table we own, what we want is to see ALL those query jobs across all those projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that you can get this information through [Google Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging).

The following command extracted the logs of all queries across the org referencing tables within `<DATASET_ID>`.

```
gcloud logging read 'timestamp >= "2022-09-01T00:00:00Z" AND resource.type=bigquery_dataset AND resource.labels.dataset_id=<DATASET_ID> AND severity=INFO'
```

Important that this command needs to be run from the project on which `<DATASET_ID>` exists and you need the `roles/logging.admin` role.

Worth to note that I was not able to test the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION` which should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible to access all the query jobs across the entire organization that reference a specific table.

As you have mentioned you can list query jobs within the project using the query as:

```
select * from `PROJECT_ID`.`region-REGION_NAME`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
where job_type = 'QUERY'
```

PROJECT_ID is the ID of your Cloud project. If not specified, the default project is used.
You can use the query without the `project-id` as:

```
select * from `region-REGION_NAME`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
where job_type = 'QUERY'
```

For more information you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs#scope_and_syntax).

If you want the feature to list query jobs across the entire organization   be implemented, you can open a new [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) on the issue tracker describing your requirement.